# For which $a > 0$ the sum $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(a^n\cdot\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k})$ converges?

Tags: calculus, summation

For which $a > 0$ the sum $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(a^n\cdot\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k})$ converges ?

**Attempt**:

The pattern of the sum is $1\cdot a^1 + (1+\frac{1}{2})\cdot a^2+(1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3})\cdot a^3 +\dots(1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\dots+\frac{1}{n})\cdot a^n$

I hardly have an idea how to solve this question I tried to separate the sum but I didn't succeed

Thanks.

Comment: $ \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} \frac 1  k \sim \ln \, n$ and $\sum a^{n} \ln \, n<\infty$ iff $|a|<1$.

Comment: Yes but I can know that $\frac{1}{n}$ ~~$ln (n)$? its based with i don't know that

Comment: For $|\alpha|<1$, $\sum_{k=1}^n\frac 1k \leq n$  is enough to conclude that the series converges. For $|\alpha|\geq 1$, $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k} \geq 1$ is enough to conclude that the series diverges.

Comment: @Epsilon1 The sum can be given explicitly. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $b_n:=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k}$. Then

$$1 \le b_n \le n$$

for all $n$. This gives

$$(*) \quad a^n \le a^n b_n \le n a^n$$

for all $n$.

Since $ \sum a^n$ and $ \sum na^n$ are convergent $ \iff |a|<1$, it follows from $(*)$, that $ \sum a^nb_n$ converges $ \iff |a|<1.$

Answer (score 2):

Fix $|a|<1.$ Let $b_0=0$ and $b_n=\sum_{k=1}^n{1\over k}.$ Then $$\displaylines{(1-a)\sum_{n=1}^\infty a^nb_n= \sum_{n=1}^\infty a^nb_n - \sum_{n=1}^\infty a^{n+1}b_n\\   = \sum_{n=1}^\infty a^n(b_n-b_{n-1})=\sum_{n=1}^\infty {1\over n}a^n  =-\log(1-a)}$$ So the result is equal $$-{\log(1-a)\over 1-a}$$

Comment: Thanks for beautiful answer, but i need only to show them what $\alpha$ the sum is converges

Comment: It is proved on the way if instead of using infinite sums you consider partial sums.